# How do i set a laravel url to be the landing page on another domain with nginx, Cloudflare

Tags: laravel, nginx, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I have my web application on something.management. I have both production and development in same digital ocean droplet with nginx and cloudflare. My devlopment have a route called /frontend. Now i want to show that page as landing page in anoter domain . How do i do that

I already tried with using location block in nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is the correct answer, but I used the laravel domain method in the route file, and now I can have two laravel domain routes like something.com and another.com.Later I redirected the request to application by using nginx